# Проблема с кодировкой в ubuntu 20.04. Разница в работе через pycharm и через терминал

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm, bs4

В чем проблема. Использую библиотеку bs4 для парсинга html страницы.

soup = bs(r.content.decode('utf-8'), 'html.parser')

Запуская код в pycharm получаю нормальный результат.
[image: текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом]

Однако запуская код через терминал получаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

export'ы на utf-8 в .bashrc использовал. И в pycharm и в линуксе везде стоит одна и та же кодировка utf-8.

В чем же может быть проблема???

Comment: Покажите более полный код, который мы сможем запустить у себя ([mcve])

Comment: в консоли Настройка - Установить кодировку - UTF-8 не пробовали сделать?